# Association Select - Update another select when one select change in EditableTable with antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to implement a EditableTable with react and antd, the table mainly has two columns in demo,
when select of 'country' changed, the options in 'city' should update according with the value of 'country'.

the demo code is like this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-shamir-qvjr9n?file=/src/App.js

but I have two problem,

1. compile issue with codesandbox, I don't known how to export the component, the following code passed in local, but it meets error with codesandbox

```
export default Form.create<EditableTableProps>()(Association);
```

2. setState failure, invoke setCityList in subcomponent, but this instance has no function setState

```
    setCityList(list: CityCode[]) {
        console.log(list);
        this.setState({cityList: list});
        console.log("cityList");
    }
```

Comment: after rename App.js to App.tsx, the first problem fixed.

Comment: done, should change `setcitylist: this.setCityList,` to `setcitylist: (val: CityCode[])=>this.setCityList(val),` in `const columnsTemp` at line 247